# PHP, remove directories

Tags: php, string

I want do delete some directories and i have their names stored in an array called folders.

```
foreach ($folders as $f){
    rmdir($dir);
    $dir=rtrim($dir,"/");
    $dir=rtrim($dir,$f);
}
```

**For example:**

```
dir: /cdf5/gfft/
and folders: gftt,cdf5
```

I saw that sometimes the rtrim function cut more than 4 characters and the remaining path in dir is: `/cdf`.

What's the problem?

Comment: share your `$folders` array to us.

Comment: Where is `$dir` defined?

Comment: If you only want to remove trailing slash use substr its a cheaper action for the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function deletes directory with files inside

```
function deldirectory($dir){

$tfile = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($tfile,
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()){
        rmdir($file->getRealPath());
    } else {
        unlink($file->getRealPath());
    }
}
return rmdir($dir);
}
```

Then you can call this function

```
foreach ($folders as $f){
    deldirectory($f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why my solution doesn't work?

Comment: it may be having files or subdirectory inside so it will not work. rmdir removes only empty directory. So you have delete the files and subdirectories first before deleting the directory.